# Compare two similar objects in C# tests

Tags: c#

Is there an existing assert to assert 2 similar objects?

I tried using `Assert.Equal` but it doesn't work correctly on objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar" objects? And do your classes implement `Equals()`/`HashCode()`?

Comment: @Progman I mean same classes. Compare person1 to person2. No, I don't implemented these methods.

Comment: See also the `record` keyword in C# 9.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static bool IsEqual(this object obj, object another)
{
  if (ReferenceEquals(obj, another)) return true;
  if ((obj == null) || (another == null)) return false;
  if (obj.GetType() != another.GetType()) return false;

  var objJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
  var anotherJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(another);

  return objJson == anotherJson;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the fields of the objects for example:

```
Customer actual = new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "John" };
Customer expected = new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "John" };

Assert.Equal(expected, actual); // The test will fail here
```

you can compare doing that:

```
Assert.Equal(expected.Id, actual.Id);
Assert.Equal(expected.Name, actual.Name);
```